# Why is SQL GROUP_CONCAT Query not working?

Tags: mysql

I have this query, but it gives me duplicate values in row

```
select products.name, products.image, products.image_second, 
products.description, products.min_order, size_categories.size_id, 
products.id, 
GROUP_CONCAT( product_prices.price order by FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id)) as price,
GROUP_CONCAT( sizes.name order by FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id) ) as sizes_name, 
units.name as units_name 
from `products` 
inner join `subcategories` on `products`.`subcategories_id` = `subcategories`.`id` 
inner join `size_categories` on `subcategories`.`categories_id` = `size_categories`.`categories_id` 
inner join `sizes` on FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id) > '0' 
inner join `units` on `units`.`id` = `products`.`units_id` 
inner join product_prices on product_prices.products_id = products.id 
where `products`.`id` = '1' 
group by `products`.`name`, `products`.`image`, 
`products`.`image_second`, 
`products`.`description`, `products`.`min_order`, 
`size_categories`.`size_id`, `products`.`id`
```

The result is like this

```
------ size_id | id | price          | sizes_name
------  1,2       1   43,32,43,32       2m,2m,3m,3m
```

32 is the price of 2m, and 43 is the price of 3m.
I need it in a single row and also i need to maintain the order (it should be like 32,43 and not like 43,32)
like

```
------ size_id | id | price | sizes_name
------  1,2       1   32,43     2m,3m
```

Please Help

Comment: Use DISTINCT: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT...)`

Comment: it works, if i use distinct in both group_concat's but what about the order?

Comment: the result i'm getting is price `43,32` and sizes_name `2m,3m`. 32 is the price of 2m. How can i keep it in order?

Comment: Post sample data in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7 so we can test it.

Comment: I posted it, please check it out

Comment: You must post a link here or inside the question.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=67da883152e4ffb6df2cc25b96d5d5c6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the condition:

```
...and product_prices.size_id = sizes.id
```

when you join `product_prices`.
With this condition you don't need `DISTINCT` inside `GROUP_CONCAT()` for this sample data, although it may be needed for your actual data:

```
select products.name, size_categories.size_id, products.id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(product_prices.price order by FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id)) as price,
GROUP_CONCAT(sizes.name order by FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id)) as sizes_name 
from products 
inner join subcategories on products.subcategories_id = subcategories.id 
inner join size_categories on subcategories.categories_id = size_categories.categories_id 
inner join sizes on FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id)
inner join product_prices on product_prices.products_id = products.id and product_prices.size_id = sizes.id 
where products.id = '1' 
group by products.name, size_categories.size_id, products.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a539fc41891988734debedbd4814f70d).
Results:

```
> name | size_id | id | price | sizes_name
> :--- | :------ | -: | :---- | :---------
> PR1  | 1,2     |  1 | 32,43 | 2m,3m
```